# Concat 2 input values and bind result to input

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have 2 input values 
Here is how it look like

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label>{{l("RoomLength")}}</label>
                    <input number-directive #roomLengthInput="ngModel" class="form-control nospinner-input" type="text" name="roomLength" [(ngModel)]="room.roomLength"   maxlength="32">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>{{l("RoomWidth")}}</label>
                    <input number-directive #roomWidthInput="ngModel" class="form-control nospinner-input" type="text" name="roomWidth" [(ngModel)]="room.roomWidth"   maxlength="32">
                </div>
```

And I need to concat those values into one value and bind to this input

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label>{{l("TotalSize")}}</label>
                    <input number-directive #totalSizeInput="ngModel" class="form-control nospinner-input" type="text" name="totalSize" [(ngModel)]="room.totalSize"   maxlength="32">
                </div>
```

How I can do this?

Comment: How is it supposed to work when you edit `totalSize`? Should it modify `roomLength` or `roomWidth`?

Comment: Nope. It should not update, this field will be readonly @ConnorsFan

Comment: And what is the mathematical relationship between the three values?

Comment: total = length*width @ConnorsFan

Comment: You could use one-way binding: `[ngModel]="room.roomLength * room.roomWidth"`.

Comment: But I need to bind it to model, to send to back-end , like I already have `[(ngModel)]="room.totalSize"`. So your answer is not good idea @ConnorsFan

Comment: Then define the total as a getter property: `get totalSize(): number { return this.roomLength * this.roomWidth; }`. By the way, if the total is a calculation of the other two fields, you may not have to save it in the database.

Comment: Can I do this on ts side, via ngModelChange? @ConnorsFan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen for **ngModelChange** event on both inputs(room.roomLength and room.roomWidth) and update the room.totalSize on eventHandler of that.

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label>{{l("RoomLength")}}</label>
                    <input number-directive #roomLengthInput="ngModel" class="form-control nospinner-input" type="text" name="roomLength" [(ngModel)]="room.roomLength" (ngModelChange)="updateSize()"   maxlength="32">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>{{l("RoomWidth")}}</label>
                    <input number-directive #roomWidthInput="ngModel" class="form-control nospinner-input" type="text" name="roomWidth" [(ngModel)]="room.roomWidth" (ngModelChange)="updateSize()"   maxlength="32">
                </div>
```

In your component.ts file,

```
updateSize() {
   this.totalSize = this.room.roomWidth + this.room.roomLength
}
```

Comment: It helps. Thank's

Comment: Glad to help you.